# Unable to boot Android in a multiboot PC configuration

Tags: android-x86, dual-boot

I installed "android x86 4.0 rc1 asus_laptop iso" on `/sda3` (NTFS partition created in Windows 7) of my Advent Verona recently. I already run Windows 7 and Linux Mint 11 so was dual booting with GRUB.

When I installed Android it took over the Mint bootloader and would not show Mint in its bootloader, but I was able to correct the problem, thereby getting the Mint loader back, through [this site](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repairrestorereinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd/).

However, this caused Android to disappear from the bootloader. I tried to get it to appear so I could load it from there and was able to do so using [this information](http://groups.google.com/group/android-x86/browse_thread/thread/ee20ba0426f52334).

I've been able to edit the file that makes you see all the OS on the laptop and I see all the three OSes now. I can load into Windows 7 and Linux Mint without problems but when I try to boot Android I get these errors on a black page:

```
[numbers] VFS: could not find a valid V7 on sda3
[numbers] kernel panic - not syncing: vfs: unable to mount root fs on unknown block (8.3)
[numbers] Pid. 1 comm: swapper not Tainted 3.0.8 android x86 asus_laptop
```

Then it reboots after a few seconds. What am I not doing right?

Comment: think this question is more of a fit for [superuser](http://superuser.com) as its governing bootloader and grub....

Comment: I'm inclined to say that this is alright here for now. Although Super User would likely take it as well, this is probably a pretty standard procedure for anyone who wants to install Android x86 in a multiboot configuration. The answer may well lie in the GRUB config, but I think that just creates overlap with SU here and doesn't necessarily make this off-topic for us.

Comment: There's this: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/03/how-to-dual-boot-android-x86-and-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 5):

The one thing that sticks out from your question is that `/sda3` is NTFS-formatted

> on /sda3 (NTFS partition created in Windows 7)

and thus the Android's Linux kernel *panic*'s due to not understanding NTFS.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue and excluded the posibility that NTFS is the problem since I tried everything on a FAT32 partition.

I think it has something to do with the drive geometry not being aligned properly thus the errors. (in my situation, everything else (OSes) work fine)

Comment: This should be comment rather than an answer.